# Can we create private chat rooms in django channels and send notifications

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

I am working on my personal project and stuck on a logic
I am creating a application in which users can search coding articles posted by another user 
Once user searches an article, I want to show if the author of that user is online and if the author of that post is online, ask (notification will be sent to) the author for chat and if author accepts the chat connect both of them to a chat room
The author is logged in and the user who is searching the post is by default not logged in

Currently I am not able to do with properly I am using long polling

Using django channels
Please help me out with this
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad and abstract, If you want to use Django channels for your problem, then learn it, start doing something and if you run into an issue, you can post a specific question. As it is now, it is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: Actually I am not able to think a logic , when a user searches any post the author of that post should receive a notification if author is online,

Comment: I am not able to implement of checking the author is online/offline and then sending them the notification

Comment: Please help me in solving this project

Comment: Check this question for offline/online implementation in channels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931038/django-how-to-track-if-a-user-is-online-offline-in-realtime

Comment: In stackoverflow, people don't help you do your project but help you solve specific problems. So, like I already said above, you should try to start doing something on your own, then ask(or even search existing questions) specific questions when you encounter the problems